# Add Registry and edit if exist using batch Script

Tags: batch-file

I tried to add registry but If I take user prompt input the the variable is stored instead of a value

```
@echo off 
set /p RName="Enter the registry name:"
set /p Rvalue="enter the value:"
REG ADD HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console /v RName /d RValue
REG QUERY HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console /v RName
Pause
```

So RName and RValue is inserted instead of entered value entered by user at prompt

Comment: Type `set /?`. Variable names are enclosed in percent signs when using them to show you want it as a variable and not text.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it By add padding variable with % wherever it has been used.

```
@echo off 
set /p RName="Enter the registry name:"
set /p Rvalue="enter the value:"
REG ADD HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console /v %RName% /d %RValue%
REG QUERY HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console /v %RName%
Pause
```